# How to get value from options tag when not selected in nextjs

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have the following code to select options:

```
<select name='categoryName' defaultValue={article.categoryName} onChange={handleChange}>
  {categories.map((item) => <option key={item._id}>{item.categoryName}</option>)}
</select>

const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setArticle((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
};
```

On form submit, I am trying to values:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('data', article)  //categoryName is empty unless I select from dropdown
};
```

How to get default value from dropdown without using `onChange` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your intention, you can select the default value on submit using addressing your index of the intended item in the "categories", usually it has to be the first item (index [0]), so you have to do this:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   setArticle((prevState) => {
     return { ...prevState, categoryName: categories[0].categoryName }
   });
};
```

Or, you can select the default value on the initial component load ( using useEffect and empty array dependency ) or on the fetch function where you get "categories" data.